# Cassandra won't start on OSX "Reason: Connection refused."

Tags: java, cassandra

I'm working on a java project in which cassandra is included in the repository itself. I'm having trouble getting it to run however, receiving the following error:

```
/Users/xxx/dev/xxxx/build/cassandra/bin/cassandra-cli -h localhost -p 9052 -f 

/Users/xxx/dev/xxxx/schema.txt
return code: 0
stderr: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:183)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.connect(CliMain.java:73)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cli.CliMain.main(CliMain.java:249)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:178)
    ... 3 more
Exception connecting to localhost/9052. Reason: Connection refused.

stdout: Not connected to a cassandra instance.
Not connected to a cassandra instance.
```

I've tried altering the port and the localhost hostname to 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0 but this makes no difference really.

I'm using java version "1.7.0_71"

Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: You know that `cassandra-cli` does start the actual Cassandra instance, but allows you to connect to an already runnign Cassandra via a CLI? How do you actually start the Cassandra?

Comment: @Slanec i didn't, but i checked and a it's in the project gradle file as a separate command `startCassandra`. I tried running that manually and added the output to the question. It says exit code 0 but checking `ps aux` Cassandra is not running after that command.

Comment: Oh! Interesting. We're getting closer. Check the Cassandra logs. Is anything in there? Does it start at all, does it die immediatelly? If the log is not there at all, focus on the `startCassandra` command - what does it call?

Comment: the command should be fine since other devs use it without issue. i did get this console log when running startCassandra "04/12/2014 10:23:46.209 java[17243]: objc[17243]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was cassandra trying to start on a hostname that was not in my `/etc/hosts` file. 
I found which hostname by running `/Users/xxx/dev/xxxx/build/cassandra/bin/cassandra -f` which gave better output as to what the issue was.